# unable to access tab delimited text file data using OleDbConnection ACE12.0

Tags: c#, oledbconnection

I am trying to import data from text file that is tab delimited using OleDbConnection string like below

```
using (OleDbConnection con =new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + path + @";Extended Properties='text;HDR=YES;FMT=TabDelimited';"))
```

I have provided tabDelimited option in extended properties but still i am getting data for each column upto comma ie CSV delimited.

I am importing data for the first time so this is kind of new to me.

I want to insert the data into datatable and then bulk insert the datatable into database (SQL Server) but the data is not received properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the ODBC text driver, you need to supply schema information as well.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver

Basically, you need to add a file named `schema.ini` in the same directory as your text file.

This should contain two rows:

```
[yourfilename.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
```